# While importing tensor flow, I am facing this issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

```
importError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-370f0fe8bb94> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     39 
---> 40 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
     41 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     42 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     77     sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags)
     78 except ImportError:
---> 79   raise ImportError(
     80       f'{traceback.format_exc()}'
     81       f'\n\nFailed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.\n'

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `anaconda` environment and `tensorflow` could not install properly in your system.

For this, create a new environment for `tensorflow` using below code:

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow 
conda activate tf

conda install pip
pip install tensorflow
```

Select the `"tf"` environment in `anaconda` platform and open the `JUPYTER notebook` in the same environment and type this code again:

```
import tensorflow as tf
printf(tf.__version__)
```

if there is no error, means `tensorflow` installed successfully.

Please check this [link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/) for reference.